# EAP-TLS: How to verify a p12 key with freeradius?

Tags: openssl, radius, freeradius

I installed a Radius server with a EAP-TLS only configuration.
I have a `client.p12` file that is supposed to contain both the root-CA and the client certificate.

1. I added the `p12` key

   - https://documentation.meraki.com/zGeneral_Administration/Other_Topics/Freeradius%3A_Configuring_Windows_7_with_an_EAP-TLS_wireless_profile
2. I configured the SSID but in freeradius's debug messages it seems freeradius can't verify my key/certificate.

```
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
(25) eap_tls: ERROR: Program returned code (2) and output 'error /tmp/radiusd/radiusd.client.XXK1l6r6: verification failed'
tls: Certificate CN (testuser@****.com) fails external verification!
(25) eap_tls: >>> send TLS 1.2  [length 0002] 
(25) eap_tls: ERROR: TLS Alert write:fatal:internal error
tls: TLS_accept: Error in error
(25) eap_tls: ERROR: Failed in __FUNCTION__ (SSL_read): error:1417C086:SSL routines:tls_process_client_certificate:certificate verify failed
(25) eap_tls: ERROR: System call (I/O) error (-1)
(25) eap_tls: ERROR: TLS receive handshake failed during operation
(25) eap_tls: ERROR: [eaptls process] = fail
(25) eap: ERROR: Failed continuing EAP TLS (13) session.  EAP sub-module failed
(25) eap: Sending EAP Failure (code 4) ID 7 length 4
(25) eap: Failed in EAP select
(25)     [eap] = invalid
(25)   } # authenticate = invalid
(25) Failed to authenticate the user
(25) Using Post-Auth-Type Reject
(25) # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/***network
(25)   Post-Auth-Type REJECT {
(25) attr_filter.access_reject: EXPAND %{User-Name}
(25) attr_filter.access_reject:    --> testuser@@****..com
(25) attr_filter.access_reject: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 11
(25)     [attr_filter.access_reject] = updated
(25)   } # Post-Auth-Type REJECT = updated
(25) Delaying response for 1.000000 seconds
Waking up in 0.6 seconds.
Waking up in 0.3 seconds.
(25) Sending delayed response
(25) Sent Access-Reject Id 25 from 172.17.0.2:1812 to 172.17.0.1:33331 length 44
(25)   EAP-Message = 0x04070004
(25)   Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
Waking up in 3.8 seconds.
(20) Cleaning up request packet ID 20 with timestamp +1661
(21) Cleaning up request packet ID 21 with timestamp +1661
(22) Cleaning up request packet ID 22 with timestamp +1661
(23) Cleaning up request packet ID 23 with timestamp +1661
(24) Cleaning up request packet ID 24 with timestamp +1661
(25) Cleaning up request packet ID 25 with timestamp +1661
Ready to process requests
```

**Question:** How to test my freeradius server with my p12 key in CLI without having to setup everything from windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here:

- http://lists.freeradius.org/pipermail/freeradius-users/2016-March/082736.html

`client_cert` isn't necessary because the client certificate exists already in the p12 file.

**eapol_test.conf.tls**:

```
network={
        key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
        identity="myusername"
        proto=WPA2
        eap=TLS
        ca_cert="/tmp/clients/ca.pem
        # client_cert="/tmp/clients/clientcertpem" # Useless, the certificate is already in the p12 file
        private_key="/tmp/clients/client.p12"
        private_key_passwd="xxxxx"
}
```

Run the command: `eapol_test -c eapol_test.conf.tls -a 127.0.0.1 -p 1812 -s testing123 -r1`